# How to change the index to something else on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
date = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Release Date']).to_period("M")
per = df['Release Date'].dt.to_period("M")
g = df.groupby(per)
```

I want to set something different as an index but I want my data to be grouped by months of the year, because I want to be able to plot a graph with months and quantities sold, but I don't know how to. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the input data and the expected output to form a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

```
date.groupby(data['Release Date'].map(lambda x: x.month))
```

The given code was horribly written so I cannot tell what actual dataframe looks like. please use the code sample format.